# Make an ios notifications from ios website

Tags: ios

I want to build html5 application using some frontend framework like angular or vue.js and then I want to make a mobile app from it. I don't need this mobile app to be native, so that's okay.

Then I want to put it into webview to make a mobile app from it.
I know this is possible with android. Is this possible with ios?
And will it possible to send push notifications?
ps: I don't want to use react native or cordova cause it will be much more difficult and we will run over the budget for this mvp

Answer (score 0):

While technically possible, if you're planning on trying to put it on the app store, you're likely going to run afoul of the app store guidelines and will likely get rejected:

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
>   beyond a repackaged website.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Technically, all you need for a push notification is to get the mobile id (the one they register to APNS) then send a notification package to apple some way (normally a remote server) to register a new notification. My question is aside from notifications, why not just build a different sort of app like a progressive web app?